# How to chain multiple jquery animation functions?

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate

Hi I'm having some jquery troubles!

I have several buttons, that all need to launch a unique animation effect onclick. Different animation for each button!

I have a block of code i'm using that works well.
I simple want to duplicate this block of code several times, changing a few elements and values here and there, but i can't get it to work! Please help!!??

The code looks like this...

```
    $('#animation2').click(function(){
setTimeout("animation()",2000); 
});

function animation(){
    float_boat();
    sail_away();
}

function float_boat(){
    $(".boat").animate({top:"-=80px"},800).animate({top:"+=100px"}, 1200);
    setTimeout("float_boat()",2000);
}

function sail_away(){
    $(".sailboat").animate({left:"80%",marginLeft:"0px"}, 3500).fadeTo(600, 0);
}


$('#animation3').click(function(){
setTimeout("animation()",2000); 
});

function animation(){
    bounce_bike();
    ride_away();
}

function bounce_bike(){
    $(".motorbike").animate({top:"-=80px"},800).animate({top:"+=100px"}, 1200);
    setTimeout("bounce_bike()",2000);
}

function ride_away(){
    $(".motorcycle").animate({left:"80%",marginLeft:"0px"}, 3500).fadeTo(600, 0);
}

$('#animation4').click(function(){
setTimeout("animation()",2000); 
});

function animation(){
    float_balloon();
    float_away();
}

function float_balloon(){
    $(".balloon").animate({top:"-=80px"},800).animate({top:"+=100px"}, 1200);
    setTimeout("float_balloon()",2000);
}

function float_away(){
    $(".airballoon").animate({left:"80%",marginLeft:"0px"}, 3500).fadeTo(600, 0);
}
```

Comment: why not just set an anonymous function in your timeouts instead of calling a function you have defined multiple times?

Answer (score 1):

1. Never use eval, as [eval is evil](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+eval+evil&aq=f&oq=javascript+eval+evil&aqs=chrome.0.57j0l2.3284j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Simply use anonymous functions as callback for `setTimeout`:

   ```
   setTimeout(function() {
       /* do some stuff here, e.g. call animation() function */
   }, 2000);
   ```

   It will be faster, safier and much easier to read and maintain.
2. You're redefining `animation()`, that's why no matter which button you click the last defined animation will occur.
3. You could easily refactor your code:

   ```
   <button class="animate" data-animation="boat">Animate boat</button>
   <button class="animate" data-animation="bike">Animate bike</button>

   ---

   var animate = {
       boat: function() { /* do boat animation here */ };
       bike: function() { /* do bike animation here */ };
   };

   $("button.animate").on("click", function() {
       var animation $(this).data("animation");

       setTimeout(function() {
           // call appropriate animation, e.g. animate.boat(), or animate.bike()
           animate[animation]();
       }, 2000);
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Could use promises to execute all of your animations independently and then do something when they're all finished:

```
$.fn.deferredAnimate = function(options, duration, easing, callback) {
  var deferred = $.Deferred();

  $(this).animate(options, duration, easing, function() {
    callback && callback();
    deferred.resolve();
  });

  return deferred.promise();
};
```

ie, here's a carousel demo which animates two different lists (at different speeds) at the same time:

```
var PAUSE_DURATION = 1500;
var ANIMATE_DURATION1 = 1000;
var ANIMATE_DURATION2 = 2000;

var textList = $('#list1');
var imageList = $('#list2');

setTimeout(slideItem, PAUSE_DURATION);

function slideItem() {
    var currentTextLi = $('li', textList).first();
    var currentImageLi = $('li', imageList).first();

    var textPromise = currentTextLi.deferredAnimate({
        'margin-left': -375
    }, ANIMATE_DURATION1, 'easeInOutExpo', function() {
        var c = currentTextLi.remove();
        textList.append(c);
        c.css('margin-left', 0);
    });

    var imagePromise = currentImageLi.deferredAnimate({
        'margin-left': -660
    }, ANIMATE_DURATION2, 'easeInOutExpo', function() {
        var c = currentImageLi.remove();
        imageList.append(c);
        c.css('margin-left', 0);
    });

    $.when(textPromise, imagePromise).then(function() {
        //repeat the animations
        window.setTimeout(slideItem, PAUSE_DURATION);
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You use `function animation()` four times. Use `function animation1()`, `function animation2()` and so on instead.

Don't forget to make changes in `setTimeout("animation()",2000);` too (`setTimeout("animation1()",2000);` and so on)